# Large dataset with many formulae causes crashing

Tags: crash, memory-limit

I have 50000 rows and 30 columns with relatively long formulae. I have tried to extend formulae in the columns to all rows, but Excel crashes. Is there a trick to do it in parts? I tried first some columns and then replaced the cells with "values" only (paste as values), but this did not work out. Any other tricks?

Is this a memory problem?

I have i5 8th gen, 16gb of ram, 2 years old Lenovo ThinkPad

Comment: What version of MS Office?  Did you apply all updates and service packs?

Comment: Thanks! I updated office to newest 64bit  version and everything started to work, though takes half an hour with 500,000 rows.

Comment: Well if you have a standard hard drive,  I recommend an SSD.